# Does iFrame really load javascript separately from parent page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

I have main page which loading `jquery-1.7.2.min.js` and `jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js` following with `jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css`. In my main page, I have used jQuery UI Tab by set `$('#main_tabs').tabs();` inside `$(function($){ });` and also used iFrame to load another page.

```
$(function($){
     // Tabs
     $('#main_tabs').tabs();
});
```

Inside the page that will be loaded into iFrame, which hosted in the same directory, `jquery-1.5.min.js` and third-party javaScript library (called `timeline.js`) is loaded. The javaScript code in timeline.js somehow uses `jquery-1.5.min.js` (must be loaded before this third-party library), so the page will work as it should be.

Some example of script in timeline.js

```
// javaScritp Class defined here
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.browser.isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
    $.browser.isMac = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('macintosh') > -1;
    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version >= 9) {
        $.browser.msie = false;
        $.browser.isIE9 = true;
    }
    theAJKWindowResizeEvent = new AJKWindowResizeEvent().init();
    theAJKMouseMoveEvent = new AJKMouseMoveEvent().init();
    theAJKMouseScrollEvent = new AJKMouseScrollEvent(
                    …. //more code
});
```

The thing is when load the main page (on Firefox with firebug turn on) there are errors, and that errors make me confuse with iFrame.

Some of errors show as below (not in an order, the order changed every time when I try to reload)

```
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.
Script: http://localhost/TMCH/js/jquery/jquery-1.5.min.js:16 

A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.
Script: http://localhost/TMCH/js/jquery/ jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2 

A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.
Script: http://localhost/TMCH/js/timeline.js?version=6.035:5532
```

I have try to debug those error, and find out that if I comment on `$('#main_tabs').tabs();` (avoid to use jQuery UI), there is no error. The page in iFrame loaded just fine, but my main page look ugly and totally messy as the UI is not called.

Is anyone can explain Why this thing is happen? Any solution is very appreciated

Comment: Can you post the HTML or make a jsfiddle so we can have a look?